# How to add a mean line to a xyplot in R?

Tags: r, lattice

Hi I am trying to add a mean line to a lattice xyplot using the following code... which doesn't work...

```
library(lattice)
temp <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
      c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1),
      c(1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2),
      c(0,0,0,150,150,0,0,0),
      c(3,10,4,15,14,2,4,5))
names(temp) <- c("instNo","NoOfAC","NoReleaseLevels","trExt","maxDelay")

tempavg <- aggregate(temp[5], by=list(temp$NoOfAC,temp$NoReleaseLevels
                                  ,temp$trExt),FUN = mean)

names(tempavg) <- c("NoOfAC","NoReleaseLevels","trExt","meanDelay")
xyplot(maxDelay ~ NoOfAC |trExt + NoReleaseLevels,
             data = temp,
             panel = function(x, y, tempavg) {
               panel.xyplot(x, y)
               panel.abline(tempavg$meanDelay ~ y |trExt + NoReleaseLevels)
             },
xlab = "Number Of Aircraft in the Instance",
ylab = "Total Delay (minutes)")
```

Comment: The code you've supplied to create `temp` doesn't come even close to working. (Try copy and pasting it into a fresh R session to see that.) If you have `temp` from some other source, maybe do `dput(head(temp,9))` and paste that into your question to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your approach is where does it say that `panel.abline()` takes a formula as its first argument? (It doesn't!) What `?panel.abline` says is that it takes arguments `h` and `v` (in particular for the case you have in mind) and you want argument `h`.

Note also that **lattice** calls the panel functions with arguments `x` and `y` containing the `x` and `y` data for each panel drawn. You don't need to do the subsetting and aggregating externally for this work; it is done for you. Hence you need to think in terms of `x` and `y` when drawing with panel functions.

In this case, you want `panel.abline(h = mean(y), ...)` in your panel function. The `...` is there to allow extra arguments passed to the panel function to propagate down to the function calls within the panel function. Hence your anonymous panel function also needs to take a `...` argument. This is shown below.

```
## code as factor
temp <- transform(temp, NoOfAC = factor(NoOfAC))

## plot
xyplot(maxDelay ~ NoOfAC |trExt + NoReleaseLevels,
             data = temp,
             panel = function(x, y, ...) {
               panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
               panel.linejoin(x, y, horizontal = FALSE, ...)
             },
       xlab = "Number Of Aircraft in the Instance",
       ylab = "Total Delay (minutes)")
```

Comment: That adds the mean to all values which are in y. I need it to find the mean for each graph and for each separate value of NoOfAC in each graph

Comment: No it doesn't. Did you even try it? I have a plot with 4 panels, with a line drawn at the panel mean of `y`. This corresponds to 4 of the 5 values in your `tempavg`. Perhaps you haven't explained your problem well enough - why are there 4 panels but 5 means in `tempavg`? Hard to help you if you don't explain clearly what you want.

Comment: @Tania If you want to pass in data, then you can do this via `...`, but then you'll have to work out which panel you are on (see `?panel.number`) and choose the values from the passed in `tempavg` according to `panel.number()`. That strikes me as a hack at best. Instead, if `NoOfAC` is being treated as categorical, why not code it as such and condition on it? Then **Lattice** may more easily do what you want.

Comment: Yes I did try it. Sorry if my question was unclear. The graph contains 4 separate graphs. I am trying to draw a line in each one of them between the mean value of the instances where "NoOfAC" is equal to 1 and those where "NoOfAC" is equal to 2. E.G. in the first plot on the second row there will be a line connecting (1,8.5) and (2,4)

Comment: In my real data NoOfAC has 17 levels, so it will be hard... that's if I'm understanding your suggestion correctly?

Comment: Then code `NoOfAC` as a factor and look at `panel.linejoin()` for starters. I think the edited function now does what you want?

Comment: You are a saint! That does work now :) I'd give you a massive hug if you were here right now

Comment: Work and let me do the same :P